# AWS CloudWatch alarm not populating data points - Insufficient state always

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2, disk-space-utilization, performance-monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

I am configuring CloudWatch alarm from the custom metric. Custom metric for disk space is configured, and I can see that every 5 minutes I am able to see the data. But when I set the alarm, the data points are not shown. For example:

1. Image below is the initial stats for creating an alarm
   [image]
2. Image below is after I change the name (or anything else).
   [image]

Please note that after the edit, the data points are not visible. Just because of this the alarm is in the state of Insufficient data always. Can someone please help me here? Any guidance would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of custom or standard metrics, it took me more time than I'd care to admit reviewing the following information before my CloudWatch alarms actually went from INSUFFICIENT_DATA to OK.  It's my understanding that after any change to a CloudWatch alarm the CloudWatch alarm may go into a status of "INSUFFICIENT_DATA" for a brief period of time before having a status of "OK".

[Evaluating an Alarm ==> This Section Was Helpful To Me](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html)

Answering the following trouble-shooting questions may help to uncover the cause:

- What does your script look like?
- How frequent are you calling and
  running your script?